# NetCore App Published on IIS only work with Development Environment Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I've published an application to IIS and since I'm trying to access it, I'm having trouble with the environment variable.

I've followed these steps [Setting up Env. Variables Manually](https://www.andrecarlucci.com/en/setting-environment-variables-for-asp-net-core-when-publishing-on-iis/)

If if I configure it as Development the application works fine but if I set it up as Production the following error message keeps showing up in the screen: [Production Error Screen](https://prnt.sc/q1y36g)

The applications is being deployed on a Windows Server 2019 Standard Edition with IIS 10.
Authentications method: Anonymous Authentication

Here's my Program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace SistemaGestor.SOO.Mvc
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

Here's my Startup.cs without the **using directives**:

```
namespace SistemaGestor.SOO.Mvc
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<SOOContext>(srv => SOOContextFactory.CreateInstance(Configuration));
            //Fernando Milanez 25/09/2019
            services.AddTransient<IVesselInterface,VesselRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<ICountryFlagInterface, CountryFlagRepository>();
            services.AddTransient<IAutenticacao, AutenticacaoRepositorio>();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.LoginPath = "/Autenticacao/Login";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            });

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
                .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            RequestLocalizationOptions localizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("pt-BR") },
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("pt-BR")
            };
            app.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseAuthentication(); //Requisito para ativar a autenticao, então é sempre assim adiciono o middlewaree depois defino para usar
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Autenticacao}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you get the .NET core app work without setting any additional environment variable? Because it seems that your app has already run in  production mode.

Comment: @JokiesDing only in debug mode. The problem is when I publish the app in release mode.

Comment: Its very strange. Have you tried to analyze dump file to find the real exception? WINDBG and C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\x.x.x\sos.dll can help you achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

I made this same mistake not long ago setting up my website.

Make sure you use a System Environment Variable, and not a user environment variable.

[System Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqn0e.png)

I don't know if it will help, but I have a couple of Nuget packages that might help:
DataJuggler.Core.UltimateHelper (Dot Net Framework)
DataJuggler.UltimateHelper.Core (Dot Net Core)
The first one for Dot Net Framework was released in 2012 is why the names are confusing.

There is a class called EnvironmentVariableHelper that makes it simple to get environment variables:

```
string value = GetEnvironmentVariableValue(string value);
```